# AS 3.0 How to addChild of a Sprite thats defined on a Class in a .as file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have defined some sprites in a class .as file and I want to put them in the screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Sprite Object

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class CircleObject extends Sprite{
        public function CircleObject() {
            // constructor code
            var _circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
            with(_circle.graphics){
                beginFill(0xff0000,1);
                drawCircle(0,0,30);
                endFill();
            }
            addChild(_circle);
        }
    }   
}
```

//adding it on the stage

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class Main0 extends Sprite{
        public function Main0() {
            // constructor code
            var circle:CircleObject = new CircleObject();
            addChild(circle);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question. If you have access to your sprites and you have access to the container that will hold them then you do this:

```
container.addChild(mySprite);
```